# How do I make gradle work in a multi-stage build with caching and multiple builds running?

Tags: docker, gradle

I have a `Dockerfile`s that follow this starting pattern.

```
FROM gradle:7 AS deps
COPY ./*.gradle /home/gradle
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=init-gradle \
    --mount=type=cache,target=/home/gradle/.gradle/caches/jars-9 \
    --mount=type=cache,target=/home/gradle/.gradle/caches/modules-2 \
  cp /run/secrets/init-gradle /home/gradle/.gradle/init.gradle && \
  gradle -q --no-daemon dependencies && \
  rm /home/gradle/.gradle/init.gradle
COPY ./src/ /home/gradle/src/

FROM deps AS builder
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=init-gradle \
    --mount=type=cache,target=/home/gradle/.gradle/caches/jars-9 \
    --mount=type=cache,target=/home/gradle/.gradle/caches/modules-2 \
  cp /run/secrets/init-gradle /home/gradle/.gradle/init.gradle && \
  gradle -q --no-daemon build -x test && \
  rm /home/gradle/.gradle/init.gradle
```

But what happens is if I do a `docker compose build` with multiple service images

```
#0 72.50 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
#0 72.50
#0 72.50 * What went wrong:
#0 72.50 Timeout waiting to lock jars (/home/gradle/.gradle/caches/jars-9). It is currently in use by another Gradle instance.
#0 72.50 Owner PID: 46
#0 72.50 Our PID: 45
#0 72.50 Owner Operation:
#0 72.51 Our operation:
#0 72.51 Lock file: /home/gradle/.gradle/caches/jars-9/jars-9.lock
```

What I've done was add the following before I start a `gradle` operation.

```bash
(find /home/gradle/.gradle -type f -name "*.lock" -delete || true) &&  \
```

```
FROM gradle:7 AS deps
COPY ./*.gradle /home/gradle
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=init-gradle \
    --mount=type=cache,target=/home/gradle/.gradle/caches/jars-9 \
    --mount=type=cache,target=/home/gradle/.gradle/caches/modules-2 \
  cp /run/secrets/init-gradle /home/gradle/.gradle/init.gradle && \
  (find /home/gradle/.gradle -type f -name "*.lock" -delete || true) && \
  gradle -q --no-daemon dependencies && \
  rm /home/gradle/.gradle/init.gradle
COPY ./src/ /home/gradle/src/

FROM deps AS builder
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=init-gradle \
    --mount=type=cache,target=/home/gradle/.gradle/caches/jars-9 \
    --mount=type=cache,target=/home/gradle/.gradle/caches/modules-2 \
  cp /run/secrets/init-gradle /home/gradle/.gradle/init.gradle && \
  (find /home/gradle/.gradle -type f -name "*.lock" -delete || true) && \
  gradle -q --no-daemon build -x test && \
  rm /home/gradle/.gradle/init.gradle
```

But I was wondering if there's a proper gradle parameter to prevent this problem?  So far the only information my colleague has found was [creating a read only cache via a seed build](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_resolution.html#sub:shared-readonly-cache).  Which adds a bit of complexity as we have to somehow create a build that knows about every project dependency at the beginning somehow (which may be doable in a monorepo type project).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a clean answer because there's no facility available for Gradle itself to download dependencies alone and because of that the build to capture the cached data needs to be `locked`.

```
FROM docker-proxy.devhaus.com/library/gradle:8.2 AS deps
WORKDIR /w
COPY --link . /w/
ENV GRADLE_RO_DEP_CACHE=/var/lib/gradle/caches
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=init-gradle,dst=/home/gradle/.gradle/init.gradle \
    --mount=type=cache,sharing=locked,target=/var/lib/gradle/caches \
  gradle --no-daemon build -x test -x spotlessCheck && \
  find /home/gradle/.gradle/caches/ -type f \( -name "*.lock" -o -name "gc.properties" \) -prune -o -exec cp -au --parents {} $GRADLE_RO_DEP_CACHE \;
```

The `sharing=locked` will prevent simultaneous builds, but because of the `$GRADLE_RO_DEP_CACHE` the dependencies are cached so it trims the build time significantly if it is dependency dependent.